# Is there a way in R to make an ifelse on defined consecutive rows?

Tags: r

If I have:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1,1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2, 4,4,4,4), 
              value=c("A","B","C","B","A","A","A","B","D","A","A","B"))
```

I want to make an ifelse statement or equivalent for whether any "3 in a row" starting from the first row within a group has certain values. So for example, starting in group 1 I want to scan A B C, then B C B, then C B A, and maybe making a 'want' column of if 'C' shows in every scan or not. Something like this:

```
  group value want_any_c want_any_b
1      1     A        yes        yes
2      1     B        yes        yes
3      1     C        yes        yes
4      1     B        yes        yes
5      1     A        yes        yes
6      2     A         no        yes
7      2     A         no        yes
8      2     B         no        yes
9      4     D         no        yes
10     4     A         no        yes
11     4     A         no        yes
12     4     B         no        yes
```

follow up: I want to also see if EVERY scan of 3 contains a value, starting from the first row in a group then the second group etc. (i.e. group 1 scan ABC, BCB, CBA, group 2 scan AAB, and group 4 scan DAA, AAB.) (ty akrun):

```
  group value want_any_c want_any_b want_every_c want_every_b
1      1     A        yes        yes          yes          yes
2      1     B        yes        yes          yes          yes
3      1     C        yes        yes          yes          yes
4      1     B        yes        yes          yes          yes
5      1     A        yes        yes          yes          yes
6      2     A         no        yes           no          yes
7      2     A         no        yes           no          yes
8      2     B         no        yes           no          yes
9      4     D         no        yes           no           no
10     4     A         no        yes           no           no
11     4     A         no        yes           no           no
12     4     B         no        yes           no           no
```

Comment: Can you check whetger the 'want_every_c' and 'want_every_b' column values are correct

Comment: yes they are correct, group 4 want_every_b is DAA then AAB so not evey scan has B. Same with the AAB scan in group 2, (there is no C)

Comment: If I do a rolling values, it would be `A B C`, `B C B`, `C B A`, `B A A`, `A A A`, so only the first 3 rows of group 1 have 'C'

Comment: @akrun ABC, BCB, CBA would be desired, but not BAA (A is part of group 2) and AAA (AA is part of group 2)  because these values start to dip into group 2

Comment: But, your 4th and 5th rows are "yes".  Is it done from the reverse?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan yes you're right, my follow up question tried to fix my mistake

Comment: @akrun yes, only because I want to say "GROUP 1 has all scans of three with a C in it". so I want the want labels to always be yes or always be no (do all desired scans within a group have C? if yes then group=yes, if no then group=no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `any` or `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(want_any_c = c('no', 'yes')[('C' %in% value) + 1],
           want_any_b = c('no', 'yes')[('B' %in% value) + 1])
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group value want_any_c want_any_b
#   <dbl> <fct> <chr>      <chr>     
# 1     1 A     yes        yes       
# 2     1 B     yes        yes       
# 3     1 C     yes        yes       
# 4     1 B     yes        yes       
# 5     1 A     yes        yes       
# 6     2 A     no         yes       
# 7     2 A     no         yes       
# 8     2 B     no         yes       
# 9     4 D     no         yes       
#10     4 A     no         yes       
#11     4 A     no         yes       
#12     4 B     no         yes
```

---

If it is every scan of 3 values, create another group with `gl`

```
library(zoo)
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(want_any_c = c('no', 'yes')[('C' %in% value) + 1],
        want_any_b = c('no', 'yes')[('B' %in% value) + 1],
        want_every_c = c('no', 'yes')[(all(rollapply(value, 3,
             FUN = function(x) 'C' %in% x))) + 1],
        want_every_b = c('no', 'yes')[(all(rollapply(value, 3, 
             FUN = function(x) 'B' %in% x))) + 1])
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group value want_any_c want_any_b want_every_c want_every_b
#   <dbl> <fct> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       
# 1     1 A     yes        yes        yes          yes         
# 2     1 B     yes        yes        yes          yes         
# 3     1 C     yes        yes        yes          yes         
# 4     1 B     yes        yes        yes          yes         
# 5     1 A     yes        yes        yes          yes         
# 6     2 A     no         yes        no           yes         
# 7     2 A     no         yes        no           yes         
# 8     2 B     no         yes        no           yes         
# 9     4 D     no         yes        no           no          
#10     4 A     no         yes        no           no          
#11     4 A     no         yes        no           no          
#12     4 B     no         yes        no           no
```

As it is done on multiple values, a function would be more useful

```
f1 <- function(colNm, val){
          c('no', 'yes')[(val %in% {{colNm}}) + 1]
 }


f2 <- function(colNm, val){
        c('no', 'yes')[(all(rollapply({{colNm}}, 3, 
             FUN = function(x) val %in% x))) + 1]
 }

df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(want_any_c = f1(value, "C"), 
           want_any_b = f1(value, "B"),
           want_every_c = f2(value, "C"),
           want_every_b = f2(value, "B"))
```

Comment: for the scan of every 3 values, very close but I am getting a 'yes' for observation 12 for want_every_b

Comment: @biostatguy12 Why is your 'want_every_c` for 4:5 rows 'yes', when there are no 'C' in 'value' column

Comment: b/c for group 1 ABC has C, BCB has C, CBA has C so every scan of interest has C. If every scan has C then I want to label that group as 'yes'

Comment: @biostatguy12. Okay, so you wanted a `rollapply` scan

Comment: sometimes this code for the want_every doesn't work when observations within a group are less than 3 (i.e. they are being flagged as yes) is there a way to fix this

Comment: @biostatguy12. You can add `partial= TRUE` in the `rollapply`

Comment: @biostatguy12 I. think you need a `if/else` condition i.e. `if(n() >=3) rollapply(..) else just use `want_any_c`

Comment: can I embed an ifelse statement right before rollapply?

Comment: Not `ifelse`, but just `if/else` as we are only checking the number of rows.  I commented above about the syntax

Comment: I'm a little unsure on the syntax,: mutate(want = c('no', 'yes')[(all(if(n()>=3) rollapply(value, 3, 
             FUN = function(x) 'value' %in% x , partial=TRUE))) + 1]) ?

Comment: @biostatguy12 try `df %>%
     group_by(group) %>%
     mutate(want_any_c = f1(value, "C"), 
            want_any_b = f1(value, "B"),
            want_every_c = if(n() >=3) f2(value, "C") else want_any_c,
            want_every_b = f2(value, "B"))` similarly for want_every_b

Comment: can you explain what the +1 at the end of the arguments do?

Comment: @biostatguy12 The `%in%`  returns a logical output i.e. TRUE/FALSE.  By adding 1, the TRUE/FALSE is coerced to integer and changed the value to 2/1 which we use as index to replace the values in `c("no", "yes")`

Comment: any chance you can also explain whats happening here:
```f2 <- function(colNm, val){
        c('no', 'yes')[(all(rollapply({{colNm}}, 3, 
             FUN = function(x) val %in% x))) + 1]```


```df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(want_every_b = if(n()>=3) f2(value, "B") else "no")
```

Comment: @biostatguy12 the 'f2' function does `rollapply` on the concerned column with width 3, creates a logical vector (`val %in% x`) , check if `all` are TRUE, change it  to a numeric index (`+1`) and change the replace with `c('no', 'yes')`.  We do a group by  'group' and createe a column by having a condition `if` number of rows is greater than or equal to 3, then apply 'f2' or else just return "no"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data.table solution

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

to_check <- c('C', 'B')

df[, paste0('want_any_', to_check) := lapply(to_check, '%in%', value),
   by = group]


df[, paste0('want_every_', to_check) := 
      lapply(to_check, function(x) all(rollapply(value, 3, '%in%', x = x))),
   by = group]

df
#     group value want_any_C want_any_B want_every_C want_every_B
#  1:     1     A       TRUE       TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
#  2:     1     B       TRUE       TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
#  3:     1     C       TRUE       TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
#  4:     1     B       TRUE       TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
#  5:     1     A       TRUE       TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
#  6:     2     A      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
#  7:     2     A      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
#  8:     2     B      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
#  9:     4     D      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
# 10:     4     A      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
# 11:     4     A      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
# 12:     4     B      FALSE       TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
```

Or as yes/no

```
want_cols <- grep('want', names(df), value = T)

df[,  (want_cols) := lapply(mget(want_cols), ifelse, 'yes', 'no')]

df
#     group value want_any_C want_any_B want_every_C want_every_B
#  1:     1     A        yes        yes          yes          yes
#  2:     1     B        yes        yes          yes          yes
#  3:     1     C        yes        yes          yes          yes
#  4:     1     B        yes        yes          yes          yes
#  5:     1     A        yes        yes          yes          yes
#  6:     2     A         no        yes           no          yes
#  7:     2     A         no        yes           no          yes
#  8:     2     B         no        yes           no          yes
#  9:     4     D         no        yes           no           no
# 10:     4     A         no        yes           no           no
# 11:     4     A         no        yes           no           no
# 12:     4     B         no        yes           no           no
```

If you have millions of rows the rollapply approach might be slow. I don't think it's necessarry, there's probably a solution in checking `diff(which(value == 'C'))` (which I can't figure out at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, where you first define function `want` as below

```
want <- function(v,key,f) {
    u <- sapply(seq(length(v)-2),function(k) key %in% v[k+0:2])
    switch (f,
            "any" = rep(ifelse(any(u),"Yes","No"),length(v)),
            "every" = rep(ifelse(all(u),"Yes","No"),length(v))
    )
}
```

and then you will get the desired output through the following code:

```
dfout <- cbind(df,do.call(rbind, c(make.row.names = F,
                                   lapply(split(df,df$group), function(v) data.frame(
                                       want_any_c = want(v$value,"C","any"),
                                       want_any_b = want(v$value,"B","any"),
                                       want_every_c = want(v$value,"C","every"),
                                       want_every_b = want(v$value,"B","every"))))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   group value want_any_c want_any_b want_every_c want_every_b
1      1     A        Yes        Yes          Yes          Yes
2      1     B        Yes        Yes          Yes          Yes
3      1     C        Yes        Yes          Yes          Yes
4      1     B        Yes        Yes          Yes          Yes
5      1     A        Yes        Yes          Yes          Yes
6      2     A         No        Yes           No          Yes
7      2     A         No        Yes           No          Yes
8      2     B         No        Yes           No          Yes
9      4     D         No        Yes           No           No
10     4     A         No        Yes           No           No
11     4     A         No        Yes           No           No
12     4     B         No        Yes           No           No
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R, but doesn't require hardcoding indvidual values as vectors, and matching them etc:

```
    # Create a group of each grouping var every three rows: 
    n = 3

    df$group2 <- paste0(df$group, 

                       " - ",

                       ave(rep(1:n, ceiling(nrow(df)/n)),

                           rep(1:n, ceiling(nrow(df)/n)), 

                           FUN = seq.int)[1:nrow(df)])


    # Row-wise concatenate the unique values per group: 

    values_by_group <- aggregate(value~group2, df, FUN =

                                   function(x){

                                     paste0(unique(sort(x)),

                                            collapse = ", ")})

 # Add a vector per each unique value in df's value vector: 

values_by_group <- cbind(values_by_group, 

      setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(values_by_group), 

                        ncol = length(unique(df$value)))), 

               c(unique(sapply(df$value, as.character)))))

# Store a vector of indices of values_by_group table 
# matching the values in the original dataframe: 

vec_idx <- names(values_by_group) %in% unique(sapply(df$value, as.character))

# Match vector names with values in value vector:

values_by_group[,vec_idx] <- 

  t(vapply(strsplit(as.character(values_by_group$value), ', '),

         function(x){

           names(values_by_group)[c(vec_idx)] %in% x

           },

          logical(ncol(values_by_group)-sum(!(vec_idx)))

         )
      )


# Merge with the original dataframe, drop unwanted grouping vec:

final_df <- within(merge(df, 

                  values_by_group[,names(values_by_group) != "value"], 

                  by = "group2",

                  all.x = TRUE), rm("group2"))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1,1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2, 4,4,4,4),
                value = c("A","B","C","B","A","A","A","B","D","A","A","B"))
```